# responding to appDelegate notification from beacon

Tags: xcode5, ibeacon, nsnotifications

I am experimenting with an app that notifies a users if someone on another device with the same app is willing to connect with them.  I set up a receiving beacon in the app and also a location manager notification that is sent to the app delegate to display.  I want to have an action happen if the person receiving the notification taps on the ok button.  Here is some of my code.

// set up the receiver beacon in BeaconViewController

```
NSUUID * uid2 = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"3B257014-2C29-40E0-8E1E-1D7A9E5D0964"];
        self.beaconRegion2 = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uid2 identifier:@"com.checkers.bluetooth"];
       [self.beaconRegion2 setNotifyEntryStateOnDisplay:YES];
        [self.beaconRegion2 setNotifyOnEntry:YES];
        [self.beaconRegion2 setNotifyOnExit:YES];
```

//send the notification to the app delegate

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {

    // See if we've entered the region.
    if ([region.identifier isEqualToString:@"com.checkers.bluetooth"]) {
        UILocalNotification * notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        notification.alertBody = @"Want to play checkers?";

       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
    }
}
```

//in AppDelegate I set up the notification

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    self.locationManager.delegate= self;
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
    AlertView= [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Play a Game?"
                                                  message:notification.alertBody
                                                 delegate:NULL
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                        otherButtonTitles:@"CANCEL", nil];
    [AlertView show];

        if ([notification.alertBody isEqualToString:@"Want to play Chess?"]) {
            messageString = @"chess";
            NSLog(@"messageSting:%@",messageString);
        }}
```

//I next try to find out if the "OK" button is pressed

```
  -(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

   if (buttonIndex == 0) {
   if ([messageString isEqualToString:@"chess"]) {
        messageString3 = @"Play Chess";
    }
    }
    }
```

//finally in the BeaconViewController I want to get the results of this handed off so I can create an action in this view controller

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        messageString2 = appDelegate.messageString3;
        NSLog(@"messageSting2:%@",messageString2);
```

I get the notification and I can recognize the notification.alertBody but I cannot find out what button is being tapped or to assign a value to the messageString3 by tapping a button on the notification.

Can someone help with this.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out.  Two things 
1.  I created and synthesized the UIAlertView so I could reference just the one I wanted.
2.  If you look at the alertView it has delegate set to NULL and should be set to self.

once I did these two things everything is working great.